# Django OnToOne key to parent class given invalid name

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-models

My Django 2.2 model (trimmed to include only what I believe are the relevant sections) is as follows:

```
class DataSet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(..)
      :::

    class Meta:
        abstract = False

class SurveyRunDataSet(DataSet):
    status = models.CharField(..)
      :::

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'dataset'

class RestrictedDataSet(SurveyRunDataSet):
    date_start = models.DateField(null=True)
    date_end = models.DateField(null=True)
      :::

    # Spoonfeed DJango with parent link
    # parent_link = models.OneToOneField('SurveyRunDataSet', parent_link=True, db_column='dataset_ptr'),

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'dataset'
```

After clearing all migration files and running "django-admin makemigrations", the relevant classes in the 0001_initial.py file are as follows:

```
operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='DataSet',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True,
                           primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(..)),
                    :::
            ],
            options={
                'abstract': False,
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='SurveyRunDataSet',
            fields=[
                ('dataset_ptr',
                      models.OneToOneField(auto_created=True,
                            on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, parent_link=True,
                            primary_key=True, serialize=False, to='dataset.DataSet')),
                ('status', models.CharField(..)),
                    :::
            ],
            bases=('dataset.dataset',),
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='RestrictedDataSet',
            fields=[
                ('surveyrundataset_ptr', models.OneToOneField(auto_created=True,
                      on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, parent_link=True,
                      primary_key=True, serialize=False, to='dataset.SurveyRunDataSet')),
                ('date_start', models.DateField(null=True)),
                ('date_end', models.DateField(null=True)),
                    :::
            ],
            bases=('dataset.surveyrundataset',),
        ),
```

But when I then run a test, it fails with the error :

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'surveyrundataset_ptr' into field.
  Choices are: dataset_ptr, dataset_ptr_id, datasets, flush_date, id,
  name, primary_dataset, report, report_id, source_data_set
```

where these field names list all those included in the classes DataSet and SurveyRunDataSet (some omitted above for brevity).

I understand Django creates a OneToOneField automatically, and for this chooses the field name as the parent class name followed by '_ptr', in the above example 'surveyrundataset_ptr'. But obviously there is a mismatch with all the available fields in which it is trying to locate the name!

I also understood, or thought I did, that one can create a OneToOneField manually (the commented out code line above, with the comment "Spoonfeed DJango with parent link") and that would prevent Django from creating the default one. But when I tried that, with every conceivable combination of Boolean arguments, it ignored my OneToOneField definition and still creates its own!

So is there a way to persuade Django to create in the RestrictedDataSet class (in this example) a OneToOneField with a field name 'dataset_ptr' which will point correctly to the SurveyRunDataSet parent class?

Also, I'm slightly puzzled why the same problem does not arise with the SurveyRunDataSet class's 'dataset_ptr' OneToOneField name pointing back at *its* parent class 'DataSet'. But then maybe that would have caused a similar error if the Django migrate code had not errored before reaching that!

Any suggestions welcome.

Thanks in anticipation

P.S. Note that this is an upgrade from a 1.x version of Django which did formerly work.

Comment: Please include the full error and the full line that's erroring out.

Answer (score 0):

In reply to schillingt's request, the following is the full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 37, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 23, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 53, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django_nose/runner.py", line 308, in run_tests
    result = self.run_suite(nose_argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django_nose/runner.py", line 245, in run_suite
    addplugins=plugins_to_add)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/nose/core.py", line 121, in __init__
    **extra_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/main.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.runTests()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/nose/core.py", line 207, in runTests
    result = self.testRunner.run(self.test)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/nose/core.py", line 50, in run
    wrapper = self.config.plugins.prepareTest(test)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/nose/plugins/manager.py", line 99, in __call__
    return self.call(*arg, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/nose/plugins/manager.py", line 167, in simple
    result = meth(*arg, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django_nose/plugin.py", line 82, in prepareTest
    self.old_names = self.runner.setup_databases()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django_nose/runner.py", line 495, in setup_databases
    return super(NoseTestSuiteRunner, self).setup_databases()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 554, in setup_databases
    self.parallel, **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 174, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get('TEST', {}).get('SERIALIZE', True),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 80, in create_test_db
    self.connection._test_serialized_contents = self.serialize_db_to_string()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 123, in serialize_db_to_string
    serializers.serialize("json", get_objects(), indent=None, stream=out)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 128, in serialize
    s.serialize(queryset, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 90, in serialize
    for count, obj in enumerate(queryset, start=1):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 120, in get_objects
    yield from queryset.iterator()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 341, in _iterator
    yield from self._iterable_class(self, chunked_fetch=use_chunked_fetch, chunk_size=chunk_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 55, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1120, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 474, in as_sql
    extra_select, order_by, group_by = self.pre_sql_setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 55, in pre_sql_setup
    order_by = self.get_order_by()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 330, in get_order_by
    field, self.query.get_meta(), default_order=asc))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 704, in find_ordering_name
    field, targets, alias, joins, path, opts, transform_function = self._setup_joins(pieces, opts, alias)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 734, in _setup_joins
    field, targets, opts, joins, path, transform_function = self.query.setup_joins(pieces, opts, alias)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1504, in setup_joins
    names[:pivot], opts, allow_many, fail_on_missing=True,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1420, in names_to_path
    "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'surveyrundataset_ptr' into field. Choices are: dataset_ptr, dataset_ptr_id, datasets, flush_date, id, name, primary_dataset, report, report_id, source_data_set
```

and the following is the "RestrictedDataSet" database table definition which, ironically, looks correct :

```
postgres=# \d dataset_restricteddataset
   Table "public.dataset_restricteddataset"
         Column          |  Type   | Modifiers
-------------------------+---------+-----------
 surveyrundataset_ptr_id | integer | not null
 date_start              | date    |
 date_end                | date    |
 restricted_schema_keys  | text    | not null
 filter_expression       | text    | not null
Indexes:
    "dataset_restricteddataset_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (surveyrundataset_ptr_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "dataset_restrictedda_surveyrundataset_ptr_9ee743c7_fk_dataset_s" FOREIGN KEY (surveyrundataset_ptr_id) REFERENCES dataset_surveyrundataset(dataset_ptr_id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

and for reference, although I doubt it is relevant, following is the "SurveyRunDataSet" database table:

```
postgres=# \d dataset_surveyrundataset
      Table "public.dataset_surveyrundataset"
     Column     |         Type          | Modifiers
----------------+-----------------------+-----------
 dataset_ptr_id | integer               | not null
 status         | character varying(10) | not null
 base_dataset   | boolean               | not null
 schema_mapping | text                  | not null
 survey_run_id  | integer               |
Indexes:
    "dataset_surveyrundataset_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (dataset_ptr_id)
    "dataset_surveyrundataset_survey_run_id_8e235a8a" btree (survey_run_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "dataset_surveyrundat_dataset_ptr_id_beadb771_fk_dataset_d" FOREIGN KEY (dataset_ptr_id) REFERENCES dataset_dataset(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "dataset_surveyrundat_survey_run_id_8e235a8a_fk_survey_su" FOREIGN KEY (survey_run_id) REFERENCES survey_surveyrun(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Referenced by:
    TABLE "dataset_aggregatedataset_datasets" CONSTRAINT "dataset_aggregatedat_surveyrundataset_id_be16b27e_fk_dataset_s" FOREIGN KEY (surveyrundataset_id) REFERENCES dataset_surveyrundataset(dataset_ptr_id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "dataset_restricteddataset" CONSTRAINT "dataset_restrictedda_surveyrundataset_ptr_9ee743c7_fk_dataset_s" FOREIGN KEY (surveyrundataset_ptr_id) REFERENCES dataset_surveyrundataset(dataset_ptr_id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

One thing it does show is the foreign key pointer back to the "RestrictedDataSet" table.

Answer (score 0):

Made a bit more progress, although this only makes the problem seem more intractable!

Amending the RestrictedDataClass to start as follows does indeed prevent Django from making its own OneToOne field:

```
    class RestrictedDataSet(SurveyRunDataSet):
        """
        This acts like a regular survey run dataset except that it imposes date,
        answer and schema restrictions. These are designed to be permanent.
        """

        # Spoonfeed Django with specifically named OneToOne field
        #
        dataset_ptr_id = models.OneToOneField('SurveyRunDataSet', to_field='dataset_ptr',
                 parent_link=True, primary_key=True, related_name='restricteddataset',
                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

But then "django-admin makemigrations" errors as follows, which is understandable because RestrictedDataSet inherits from SurveyRunDataSet and thus its attributes include all the latter's :

```
    SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

    ERRORS:
    dataset.RestrictedDataSet.dataset_ptr_id: (models.E006) The field 'dataset_ptr_id'
    clashes with the field 'dataset_ptr' from model 'dataset.surveyrundataset'.
```

But if I give RestrictedDataSet a unique name, such as dataset2_ptr_id, then I'm back to the original error :

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'dataset2_ptr_id' into field.
Choices are: dataset_ptr, dataset_ptr_id, datasets, flush_date, id, name,
primary_dataset, report, report_id, source_data_set
```

So in short, in either case I get an error, and I'm caught between the devil and the deep blue sea!